How can we fill the integration bounds and define a function $s$ from the given data so that this double integral is the mean of this indefinite int?
Suppose $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ has $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\ dt = 1 \in \mathbb R$.
Define $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by $g(\alpha) = \int_{-\infty}^\alpha f(t)\ dt$ and define $h : \mathbb (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ by $h(\alpha) = g^{-1}(\alpha)$.
$$E[x] = \int x h(x)\ dx = \int x g^{-1}(x)\ dx = \int x \int s(y)\ dy\ dx$$
Then what is the natural function $s$ I'm looking for to write the expectation as a double integral? And what would be the proper bounds on the integration, so that $\int x \int s(y)\ dy\ dx$ would give the expectation of the random variable chosen by drawing a uniform independently in $(0,1)$ and simply defining your variable to be the image of $h$ under that uniform $(0,1)$. How can we define a function $s$ given $f,g,h$ as a double integral, since the expectation of a r.v. $x$ is simply $\int x\cdot V(x)\ dx$.
Am I wrong to think that $s = f$? And that this integral will only converge if multiplying $x$ with the integral of $f$ also integrates to a constant, not JUST that $f$ integrates to a constant?
Thank you for the help - feel free to redefine any aspect of this in the proper terminology, but if there is some confusion on what the question is asking, please post a comment to clarify before writing a full answer.

For example $\int 1/(1+x^2)\ dx = C$, but $\int x/(1+x^2)\ dx = \infty$ by comparison with $\sum 1/n$ should be a factor in this even being possible? That $\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)\ dx$ should also $=C$.

Or that it's that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\ dy\ dx$? That's why I posed it in this "$s$" finding format - I'm unsure of the proper function to fill in to make the property satisfied.
